# How to solve $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{1+x^3}}$?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, radicals, substitution

I have:

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{1+x^3}}$$

It seems easy but neither $t^3=1+x^3$ nor $t = \sqrt[3]{1+x^3}$ nor $t = x^3$ made integral easier. What is the way to solve it then?

Comment: @AndreasAlmgren that is what they've written

Comment: this leads to a hypergeometric function

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B1%2Fcbrt(1%2Bx%5E3),+x%5D): ouch.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel   Wolfram does not fully implement Risch alogorithm, thus  sometimes fail to detect the existence of elementary primitive.

Comment: @pisco right then. Another thing that Wolfram Alpha _can't_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This integral in fact has elementary antiderivative.

Let $x=1/u$, $dx=-du/u^2 $, we have
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1+x^3}}dx = -\int\frac{1}{u^2\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{u^3}}} du = -\int\frac{u^2}{u^3 \sqrt[3]{1+u^3}} du = -\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{d(u^3)}{u^3 \sqrt[3]{1+u^3}}$$

Letting $1+u^3 = t^3$, the original integral is transformed into
$$-\int\frac{t}{t^3-1} dt$$
from which I believe you can continue.